# Connecting dojo dgrid to solr

Tags: javascript, json, solr, dojo, dgrid

I'm trying to connect a dojo dgrid to a solr data service and need some help.
When I use `jsonp` I can get connected to the solr data and output the data result to the screen with something like this:
    dojo.require("dojo.io.script");
         function searchGoogle(){
           // Look up the node we'll stick the text under.
           var targetNode = dojo.byId("output");

```
       // The parameters to pass to xhrGet, the url, how to handle it, and the callbacks.
       var jsonpArgs = {
         url: "myExternalSolrURL",
         callbackParamName: "json.wrf",
         content: {
           wt: "json",
           rows: "12",
           start: "1",
           q: "*"
         },
         load: function(data){
           // Set the data from the search into the viewbox in nicely formatted JSON
           targetNode.innerHTML = "<pre>" + dojo.toJson(data, true) + "</pre>";
         },
         error: function(error){
           targetNode.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error;
         }
       };
       dojo.io.script.get(jsonpArgs);
     }
     dojo.ready(searchGoogle);
```

But, when I try to use `jsonrest` to connect to the solr data and get it to show up in a dgrid nothing appears to happen. This is the code I have for that:

```
<script>
    var myStore, dataStore, grid;
    require([
    "dojo/store/JsonRest",
    "dojo/store/Memory",
    "dojo/store/Cache",
    "dgrid/Grid",
    "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
    "dojo/query",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function (JsonRest, Memory, Cache, Grid, ObjectStore, query, Button, domReady) {
        myStore = Cache(JsonRest({
            target: "myExternalSolrURL", 
            idProperty: "id" 
            }), 
            Memory({ idProperty: "id" }));
        grid = new Grid({
            store: dataStore = ObjectStore({ objectStore: myStore }),
            structure: [
    { name: "Thing id", field: "id", width: "50px" },
    { name: "Name", field: "name", width: "200px" },
    { name: "detail", field: "detail", width: "200px" }
    ]
        }, "grid"); // make sure you have a target HTML element with this id
        grid.startup();
    });
</script>

<div style="height: 300px; width: 600px; margin: 10px;">
    <div id="grid">
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use dgrid instead of DataGrid?

Comment: @RichardAyotte, I changed it to dgrid (edited code in question too) Good eye but no change in what I am seeing when it is executed.

Comment: The store also needs to be Observable. http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/Observable.html

Comment: It doesn't need to be Observable just for dgrid to show data from it...  It only needs to be observable to reflect updates as they happen.

Comment: Can you post the json data returned by myExternalSolrURL along with header range on both the request and response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently part of the problem is that a Solr index is not a flat data structure like a grid or dgrid can deal with. When you have nested data returned like a Solr or ElasticSearch index will return it must be "flattened" to go into a grid. However, this sort of hierarchy of data will work with a tree vs a grid. So the next challenge is to connect to the index and flatten it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You changed your code to use dgrid, but it looks like you are still attempting to use a `dojo/data` store with dgrid.  dgrid only supports the `dojo/store` API, so stop wrapping your store in `ObjectStore`.
2. `dgrid/List` and `dgrid/Grid` do not contain store logic.  You will want to either use `dgrid/OnDemandGrid` or mix in `dgrid/extensions/Pagination`.
3. Make sure the service you are using with `dojo/store/JsonRest` [actually behaves as the store implementation expects](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/rest.html) (or use or write a diffrent `dojo/store` implementation)

Comment: Useful info but not the source problem in this case it was the data itself not lending itself to a grid.